# How to run a blocking process on a background thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a unit test script that needs tests all the rest api's. At the same time I also have a xmpp server that generates messages.

I need to run an instance of the xmpp inside my unit test to receive those messages. But the problem is that the xmpp is a blocking process.

---> self.process(block=True)

This results in the unit test stalling.

Is there any way I can run this xmpp on a background thread and continue to receive msgs and run the unit test on the main thread. If yes, can I have a code snippet which I could implement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One solution is start the server in the background in your `setUp()` routine -- ie `os.system('myserver &')`, then kill it when the test is over, in `tearDown()`
2. If you want direct control over the server, use `fork()` and follow roughly the same pattern as #1.

Example:

```
import os, sys, subprocess, time, unittest

def server():
    try:
        for _ in xrange(5, 0, -1):
            print 'ding'
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


class TestClient(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.server_pid = None
        pid = os.fork()
        if not pid:             # child
            return server()
        # parent
        self.server_pid = pid

    def test1(self):
        print 'test server, PID',self.server_pid
        time.sleep(2)

    def tearDown(self):
        if not self.server_pid:
            return
        import signal
        os.kill(self.server_pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Run with:

```
python -m unittest ptest
```

Output:

> test server, PID 16490 ding ding .test server, PID None
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 2.003s
>
> OK

Comment: But there is a race condition if the test start being executed before the server is set up.